# Recover Raid in Synology DSM 7

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage, synology

After a DSM update, an issue with Synology branded cache drives caused my pool to crash and become unavailable. The 3 dots on the bottom only had the option to remove the pool, no option to enable read/write or repair the volume. I reached out to Synology support and after a week, they were able to get the pool back in read only mode so I could back up my data.

Having remote access enabled for this long left me uneasy and so after I started backing up my data the lack of cache and the improvements it offers started to irk me. I re-added the cache and that's where my real problems began. After a long day of troubleshooting I wanted to document how to recover the pool on DSM 7 in case you find yourself in a similar predicament.

After following advice on some raid forums, I marked the drives as failed and removed a drive from the array, re-add it, only to make my issues even worse !
This was the result:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raidF1]
md2 : active raid5 sda5[6](S) sdb5[1](E) sdf5[5](E) sde5[4](E) sdd5[3](E) sdc5[2](E)
      87837992640 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/5] [_EEEEE]

md1 : active raid1 sdg2[1]
      2097088 blocks [12/1] [_U__________]

md0 : active raid1 sdg1[1]
      2490176 blocks [12/1] [_U__________]
```

Looks bad however, `mdadm -D /dev/md2 reported a much better results:`

```
#mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Aug  5 22:03:13 2022
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 87837992640 (83768.84 GiB 89946.10 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 17567598528 (16753.77 GiB 17989.22 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed May 17 21:46:40 2023
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 6
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : File01:2
           UUID : 9ef80d24:68ea4c4f:3b281ebe:790302f5
         Events : 1454

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       21        1      faulty active sync   /dev/sdb5
       2       8       37        2      faulty active sync   /dev/sdc5
       3       8       53        3      faulty active sync   /dev/sdd5
       4       8       69        4      faulty active sync   /dev/sde5
       5       8       85        5      faulty active sync   /dev/sdf5

       6       8        5        -      spare   /dev/sda5
```

To make matters worse, DSM 7 changed the underlying code so commands like  `syno_poweroff_task -d`  no longer exists !
we'll I spent a considerable amount of time to to arrive at a solution, hopefully this helps someone in dire need.

So here is how to get your array rebuilding:

My array had 2 volumes that was prevent me from stopping the array & had to unmount them using the new synology packages

```
# synostgvolume --unmount -p /volume1
# synostgvolume --unmount -p /syno_vg_reserved_area 
# synovspace -all-unload
```

This will make the array look like this: **inactive** & **NOT available** is what your looking for

```
#lvm
lvm> lvscan
  inactive          '/dev/vg2/syno_vg_reserved_area' [12.00 MiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg2/volume_1' [81.80 TiB] inherit 

lvm> lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg2/syno_vg_reserved_area
  LV Name                syno_vg_reserved_area
  VG Name                vg2
  LV UUID                2E1szd-mdDP-4kkJ-YIcF-zh1B-t3t3-1hq1Ct
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                12.00 MiB
  Current LE             3
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg2/volume_1
  LV Name                volume_1
  VG Name                vg2
  LV UUID                scFIlA-VoSt-KhC1-WP0u-DYBl-3IfY-Nrc4Cj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                81.80 TiB
  Current LE             21444608
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

You can now issue the assemble command to bring back the array, if all goes well your array will start rebuilding. Even though I messed up and didn't add the last drive :( to instantly regain my array.

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md2
# mdadm --verbose    --create /dev/md2 --chunk=64 --level=5    --raid-devices=6 missing dev/sda5 /dev/sdb5 /dev/sdc5 /dev/sdd5 /dev/sde5 /dev/sdf5
```

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed May 17 22:36:29 2023
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 87837992640 (83768.84 GiB 89946.10 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 17567598528 (16753.77 GiB 17989.22 GB)
   Raid Devices : 6
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed May 17 22:36:29 2023
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 5
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : Morpheous:2  (local to host Morpheous)
           UUID : 96f5e08a:d64e6b15:97240cc1:54309926
         Events : 1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
       2       8       37        2      active sync   /dev/sdc5
       3       8       53        3      active sync   /dev/sdd5
       4       8       69        4      active sync   /dev/sde5
       5       8       85        5      active sync   /dev/sdf5
```

And finally re-add the spare, et viola !

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sda5
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raidF1]
md2 : active raid5 sda5[6] sdf5[5] sde5[4] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      87837992640 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/5] [_UUUUU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (4341888/17567598528) finish=3980.8min speed=73531K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sdg2[1]
      2097088 blocks [12/1] [_U__________]

md0 : active raid1 sdg1[1]
      2490176 blocks [12/1] [_U__________]
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: please share the output of your solution as an answer due else it will stay inhere for ever as unresolved and pushed back to get a answer and furthermore after 24h you need to accept your answer as solution, thanks for sharing

Comment: PLEASE don't use R5 - it's danergous, storage-pro's avoid it massively.

Answer (score 0):

In DSM 7 here's how to unmount the filesystem:

```
# synostgvolume --unmount -p /volume1
# synostgvolume --unmount -p /syno_vg_reserved_area 
# synovspace -all-unload
```

stop the array& rebuild the array:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md2
# mdadm --verbose    --create /dev/md2 --chunk=64 --level=5    --raid-devices=6 missing dev/sda5 /dev/sdb5 /dev/sdc5 /dev/sdd5 /dev/sde5 /dev/sdf5
```